# adding elements to different sets from a list in python

Tags: python, list, set

Let's say I have a list named

```
mylist = []
```

This list contains sentences from a file. My question is:

1. Is there a way I can add each element of mylist into separate sets?
2. If it can be done, then how to add to different set?

My code:

```
mylist = []
wordlist = open('data.txt', 'r').read().split()
ngrams = [wordlist[i:i+5] for i in range(len(wordlist)-4)]
mylist.append(ngrams)

print mylist
```

Some edits:

My output looks like this

```
[('hello', 'there')]
[("I'm", 'using'), ('using', 'python'), ('python', 'for'), ('for', 'the'),     ('the', 'first'), ('first', 'time.')]
```

What I want to do is add each of the bigram into separate sets.

Comment: Whats with all these *n-grams* lately? What is the practical use of it?

Comment: There are no *sets* in your expected output.

Comment: The question is not clear. Put an example about the wanted output. (And take more time to correct the question !)

Comment: @Constantinius In my case, converting a range into a list of start end sets.

Comment: fara, your question is not clear; your clarification especially isn't. Please provide sample desirable output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be just misunderstanding your question, yet... are you trying any of these two?

**Creating new sets from bigrams:**

```
>>> li = [("I'm", 'using'), ('using', 'python')]
>>> [set(el) for el in li]
[set(['using', "I'm"]), set(['python', 'using'])]
```

**Adding bigrams to existing sets:**

```
>>> sets = [set([1]), set([2])]
>>> sets
[set([1]), set([2])]
>>> [sets[i].add(set_) for i, set_ in enumerate(li)]  #could be expanded in proper loop
[None, None]
>>> sets
[set([1, ("I'm", 'using')]), set([2, ('using', 'python')])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        mylist = zip(words, words[1:])
        print mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = input.split()    
zip(words, words[1:])
```